# how to fix error with quandl function get (Status 404) (Quandl Error QECx02)?

Tags: python, pandas, quandl

Hi everyone python is throwing this error everytime i try to run this code.

I have tried both methods that are applied there in the code and its not running with either of :

```
api_key = open('apikey.txt', 'r').read()

for x in friddy_states[0][1]:
   query ='CMHC/HPPU50_BC'+str(x)
   df= quandl.get(query, authtoken=api_key)
```

and also tried this way:

```
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'MY API FROM QUANDL'

for x in friddy_states[0][1]:
   query ='CMHC/HPPU50_BC'+str(x)
   df= quandl.get(query)
```

both methods showed on quandl documentation and noone is working!
THIS IS THE ACTUAL CODE:

```
import quandl
import pandas as pd
import pickle

api_key = open('apikey.txt', 'r').read()

quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'MY API FROM QUANDL'

df = quandl.get('CMHC/HPPU50_BC', authoken= api_key)

friddy_states = 
pd.read_html('https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states')

main_df = pd.DataFrame()

for x in friddy_states[0][1]:

    query ='CMHC/HPPU50_BC'+str(x)

    df= quandl.get(query, authtoken=api_key)

    if main_df.empty:
        main_df = df
    else:
        main_df = main_df.join(df)

print(main_df.head())
```

got super stuck, help is appreciate

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: not yet, had to jump it -

Comment: The code you have is retrieving information from quandl for the Canadian Mortgages and Housing Commission (CMHC) information on BC housing. You appear to be trying to add US state abbreviations appended to the BC link. There are no such links on quandl, nor are there likely to be, since CMHC probably doesn't track US real estate information by state. 

Otherwise your code seems sound. I was able to access df = quandl.get('CMHC/HPPU50_BC', authoken= api_key), using my quandl key.

Maybe try searching on [Google Dataset Search][1].


  [1]: https://toolbox.google.com/datasetsearch

Answer (score 0):

I am noticing a missing t in your get request for authtoken.

```
df = quandl.get('CMHC/HPPU50_BC', authoken= api_key)
```